# Prove by Cauchy theorem that $x_n={\sin {\frac{\pi n}{4}}}$ is a divergent sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, cauchy-sequences

The task is to prove that $x_n={\sin {\frac{\pi n}{4}}}$ $(n\in\Bbb{N})$ is not a convergent sequence by Cauchy theorem.
The thorem states that a sequence is convergent when $$\forall{\epsilon>0,\quad} \exists{N(\epsilon)\in\Bbb{N},\quad} n>N(\epsilon),\quad \forall{p\in\Bbb{N}}$$
$$|x_{(n+p)}-x_n|<\epsilon$$
In the case of being divergent I guess will have to prove that
$$\exists{\epsilon>0,\quad} \forall{N(\epsilon)\in\Bbb{N},\quad} n>N(\epsilon),\quad \exists{p\in\Bbb{N}}$$
$$|x_{(n+p)}-x_n|\ge\epsilon$$
So, I composed the (n+p) term, that is $x_{(n+p)}={\sin {\frac{\pi (n+p)}{4}}}$.
Then I wrote $$\Bigl|x_{(n+p)}-x_n\Bigl|=\Bigl|{\sin {\frac{\pi (n+p)}{4}}}-{\sin {\frac{\pi n}{4}}}\Bigl|=$$$$=\Bigl|2\sin \Bigl({{\frac{\pi (n+p)}{4}}-{\frac{\pi n}{4}}\Bigl)}\cos\Bigl({{\frac{\pi (n+p)}{4}}+{\frac{\pi n}{4}}\Bigl)}\Bigl|=$$$$=\Bigl|2\sin \Bigl({\frac{\pi p}{4}}\Bigl)\cos\Bigl({{\frac{\pi n}{2}}+{\frac{\pi p}{4}}\Bigl)}\Bigl|$$
And here I got stuck. I am not sure how to pick a value for p from $\Bbb{N}$, so that I get $|x_{(n+p)}-x_n|\ge\epsilon$ ($\epsilon$ should be a constant I guess).
Will appreciate your help and I am sorry if I wrote with mistakes (English is not my native).

Comment: Why not go simple and start from the remark that, for every $n$, $$x_{8n+2}=1\qquad x_{8n+6}=-1\ ?$$

Comment: Yes, it will be much simpler, but it clearly states in the book to prove it by Cauchy theorem. Kind of wants to check the knowledge of that theorem. That’s why I did not choose that path of solution.

Comment: And very wrong you are... Use the remark in my comment to show the sequence is not Cauchy *and then use Cauchy theorem to conclude*.

Comment: @Lucy What you call “Cauchy theorem” is a false statement. Note that you attached no quantifier to $n$. It should be$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists N(\varepsilon)\in\mathbb{N})(\forall n,p\in\mathbb{N}):n\geqslant N(\varepsilon)\implies\bigl|x_{n+p}-x_n\bigr|<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: @Did Thanks for your remark. I have already written in the way you suggest but the lecturer in the university wants me to prove it in the way I mentioned above.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos I am not quite sure how to call that way of solution or the theorem, I do not study in English, will be glad if you tell me how to call it correctly.

Comment: @Lucy The problem is not in the name. The problem is that your statement is false (even if you put $\exists$ before $n$).

Comment: The statement is the condition for a sequence to be fundamental. Cauchy claims if a sequence is convergent then it is fundamental and vice versa. If I can prove that this sequence is not fundamental then I can say that it is not convergent. My first statement is stating the conditions for being a sequence fundamental, thus convergent. The second is the opposite.

Comment: Once again (but I am not sure you are really reading the comments destined to help you): the approach I delineate in my first comment shows exactly that the sequence "is not a convergent sequence by Cauchy theorem".

Comment: @Did Thanks once more for trying to help me. If I state that $x_{8n+2}= 1$ and $x_{8n+6}=-1$, then from here we already can say that the sequence is not convergent, because a convergent sequence can only have one limit. Am i right? Then where do I use Cauchy theorem?

Comment: Maybe I have not written well my question, but I do not have to state that the sequence is not Cauchy, but to deny the convergence of this sequence by proving that the conditions of Cauchy do not work for this sequence.

Comment: That $|x_{8n+6}-x_{8n+2}|=2\geqslant\epsilon>0$ for every $n$ seems to exactly contradict the Cauchy property.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I understood what you are saying. I will write in the way you suggest but will also think to solve it in the way I wrote above. There also should be some way to get a result in that approach.

Answer (score 0):

I tried again and finally got the answer I wanted. I’ll share it in case someone else needs this approach of solution which works as well.
Above I got stuck here :$$=\Bigl|2\sin \Bigl({\frac{\pi p}{4}}\Bigl)\cos\Bigl({{\frac{\pi n}{2}}+{\frac{\pi p}{4}}\Bigl)}\Bigl|$$
As it says that $\exists{p\in\Bbb{N}}$, for proving it will be enough to show that the Cauchy theorem is false for some p. I assumed that p=1 and I got: $$=\Bigl|2\sin \Bigl({\frac{\pi}{4}}\Bigl)\cos\Bigl({{\frac{\pi n}{2}}+{\frac{\pi}{4}}\Bigl)}\Bigl|=$$$$=\Bigl|\sqrt{2}\cos\Bigl({{\frac{\pi n}{2}}+{\frac{\pi}{4}}\Bigl)}\Bigl|$$
As $n\in\Bbb{N}$, $\frac{\pi n}{2}$ can be written as
$$1.\pi k + \frac{\pi}{2}, k\in\Bbb{N},\ when \ n=2k+1$$
$$2.\pi k, k\in\Bbb{N},\ when \ n=2k$$
If n=2k+1, then, for instance, $$\Bigl|\cos\Bigl( {{\frac{3\pi}{2}}+\frac{\pi}{4}}\Bigl)\Bigl|=\Bigl|\sin {\frac{\pi}{4}}\Bigl|=\Bigl|\frac{\sqrt {2}}{2}\Bigl|$$
If n=2k, then, for example, $$\Bigl|\cos {\Bigl(\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}\Bigl)}\Bigl|=\Bigl|\cos {\frac{\pi}{4}}\Bigl|=\Bigl|\frac{\sqrt {2}}{2}\Bigl|$$
This means that in any case we will get the same result that is $\Bigl|\frac{\sqrt {2}}{2}\Bigl|$ and we can write
$$\Bigl|\sqrt{2}\cos {\frac{\pi}{4}}\Bigl|=1$$
This is the same if we write $$\Bigl|x_{(n+p)}-x_n\Bigl|=1$$ which means we showed that $\exists{\epsilon\ge {0}}$ that $$\Bigl|x_{(n+p)}-x_n\Bigl|\ge {\epsilon}=1$$